# Anagram’s all over this place

Tags: riddle, anagram

I met a fellow puzzler from a certain country and town.  When I asked where he was from, he replied

> My prefix is anagram
>   My infix is anagram
>   My suffix is anagram

Where is he from?

**Hint:** When I asked him to clarify, he said

> My prefix prefix is a horned animal
>  My prefix infix is an enlightened animal
>  My prefix suffix is a worn down animal
>  
>  My suffix prefix is the worn down animal
>  My suffix infix is a slimy animal
>  My suffix suffix is the horned animal

Comment: Obviously, he is from anagramanagramanagram. :)

Comment: is *an* anagram?

Comment: @Sensoray No I worded it appropriately and intentionally ambiguous.

Comment: Just to save anybody else the work, who thought they were being clever - there are no named locations on earth called "anagram" according to GeoNames.

Comment: How 'well known' is the town? What are the chances someone in another country has ever heard of this town?

Comment: To those who edited the title, the apostrophe was supposed to indicate that "anagram" is all over this place just... anagrammed.

Comment: You invalidated several answers with that edit (including mine). :'(

Comment: I thought about mentioning the part about the title in my answer, but it seemed so apparent.

Comment: Why is there an apostrophe in 'anagrams'?

Comment: @tyobrien Okay good, I was about to go all grammar police on you (:

Comment: Great puzzle! +1

Answer (score 43, accepted):

He is from

> [**Ramanagaram**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanagaram).

> My prefix is anagram
>   My infix is anagram
>   My suffix is anagram

> **Ramanag**, **managar**, and **nagaram** are all anagrams of *anagram*.

> My prefix prefix is a horned animal
>   My prefix infix is an enlightened animal
>   My prefix suffix is a worn down animal

> A **ram** is a male sheep with horns, a **man** is enlightened, and a **nag** is an old horse.

> My suffix prefix is the worn down animal
>   My suffix infix is a slimy animal
>   My suffix suffix is the horned animal

> A **nag** (see above), a **gar** is a type of fish, and a **ram** (see above).

Comment: You’ve got it! Did my hint that I previously added help a lot? If so I can put it back.

Comment: Yes, I did use the hint; it helps a lot in searching, which is necessary if you have never heard of the name. I will add an explanation to the hint if you add it back.

Comment: Sounds good. I added it :).  It shouldn’t take much to explain them.

Comment: Why does the wikipedia page title not have the latter on the end, but every mention includes it?

Comment: @Walt There is some discussion of the [article title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Ramanagara#Article_title).

Comment: @noedne great answer... curious that the wikipedia title isn't the same as the town name

Answer (score 15):

He is from

> Walla Walla, WA

so

> Prefix= Walla, Suffix= llaWA, Infix= lawal

which are anagrams of each other

Comment: Awesome alternate answer! But not what I was thinking.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to @TwoBitOperation's answer, it could be:

> Djibouti, Djibouti
> Prefix=Djibouti, Suffix=Djibouti, Infix=outiDjib

A key distinction between the answers being:

> Djibouti is a country, but Washington is a state

(edit)
Since that was the best I could come up with, one note about this puzzle:

> The speaker says "My [prefix|suffix|infix] is anagram", not "My home" or anything else referencing a location.

Not sure whether that's noteworthy/intentional/helpful, but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Another great answer. But the actual solution is one word.

Comment: Huh. Until seeing your answer I assumed the "WA" was Western Australia. But it turns out the Australian Walla Walla is in NSW :)

Answer (score 4):

Surely the answer is:

> ['Ili'ili](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%27Ili%27ili) (a village in American Samoa)

Because

> 'Ili is an anagram of the infixes li'i and i'il, which are also an anagram of the suffix 'ili

Comment: Does it match any of the other clues?

Comment: @smci The other clues were added [after](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/64832/revisions) I posted this answer.

Comment: Ah. But you can try to retcon ;-)